# ResultSet.next() is sometimes taking lot of time when result set is very small (0 or 1 hits)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

The `Resultset` that is returned from Oracle 11g is processed in Java by using `rs.next()`.
Sometimes (about 1 in 1000), this statement is taking very long to conclude 'false'. Sometimes even several 100 seconds. And this only happens when the result set contains 0 or 1 lines.
But again, a result set with 0 or 1 line are in 999 out of 1000 processed in a few milliseconds.

What could be a reason that `rs.next()` is sometimes taking so much time?

And although the process takes a lot of time, after a few hundred seconds have passed, the Java code continues without problem.

```
private List<SomeInfo> getCases(long medewerkerId, long ogeId, OurFilter filter,
        ZTCZoekFilter zoekFilter, InterfaceZTC.Sortering sortering) {

    List<SomeInfo> foundInfos = new ArrayList<SomeInfo>();

    String query = OurImplHelper.createQuery(medewerkerId, ogeId, filter, zoekFilter);

    CallableStatement cs = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    int rowCount = 0;

    try {
        DataSource ds = null;
        String jndiLookup = "java:/dataDS";
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup(jndiLookup);

        connection = ds.getConnection();

        cs = connection.prepareCall(query);
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);

        cs.execute();

        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);

        while (rs.next()) {
            rowCount++;
            SomeInfo caseInfo = new SomeInfo();
            caseInfo.setSomecode((String) rs.getObject(1));
            ....

            foundInfos.add(caseInfo);
        }

        if (cs != null) {
            cs.close();
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ZakenmagazijnManagerException(e.getMessage());
    }

    finally {

    }

    return foundInfos;
}
```

Comment: First think to check is if you are *stuck* in the database or in the application. A 100 second wait is more probably a locking issue in the database. The proper way is to *trace*, but wihtout knowing the RDBMS no advice is possible...

Comment: Oracle 11g is our DB. I have added this info to the question.

Comment: Then run with the [10046 trace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e16638/sqltrace.htm) with level 8 (waits) - `alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 8'`

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to close things (Connection maybe, cs, rs). Also the variable scope of `cs` seems too wide from its prepareCall.

Use try-with-resources as in:

```
try (ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1)) {
    while (rs.next()) {  
        rowCount++;
        SomeInfo someInfo = new SomeInfo();
        someInfo.setSomecode((rs.getString(1));
        foundInfo.add(someInfo);
    }
    return foundInfo;
} // rs is closed.
```

---

***My style of code:***

```
String query = OurImplHelper.createQuery(medewerkerId, ogeId, filter, zoekFilter);
try {
    String jndiLookup = "java:/dataDS";
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup(jndiLookup);

    try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
            CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(query)) {
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.execute();

        try (ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1)) {
            List<SomeInfo> foundInfos = new ArrayList<>();
            int rowCount = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                rowCount++;
                SomeInfo caseInfo = new SomeInfo();
                caseInfo.setSomecode((String) rs.getObject(1));
                ....

                foundInfos.add(caseInfo);
            }
            return foundInfos;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ZakenmagazijnManagerException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

I have updated the question with all the code in our method. Is your reply still applicable?

Comment: Thank goodness. Only the ResultSet then, can be closed explicitly.

Comment: My original answer corrected the ResultSet. Added "My style of code" to show what typing can be saved.